# Page isn't working error, Node js freezes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, amazon-dynamodb, mean-stack

I'm using Node for the first time and am having trouble when a certain response is triggered. In this case, I'm checking if the username and pw matches what I have in DynamoDB. It redirects to my page when the username and pw don't match my db, but when it does, all of my console.log output prints twice (which apparently has something to do with the favicon in Chrome) like "online" and "[pw] + database.js," but it also freezes my IDE and terminal. I then see the "The page isn't working, localhost didn't send any data" error in my browser. Ignore the privacy problems :) Thoughts?

database.js:

```
var myDB_lookup = function(username, password, route_callbck){
      console.log('Looking up: ' + username);   
      users.get(username, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          route_callbck(null, "Lookup error: "+err);
        } else if (data == null) {
          route_callbck(null, null);
        } else {
          // JSON object that stores password & fullname
          var value = JSON.parse(data[0].value);
          var pw = value.password;
          if (pw.valueOf() == password.valueOf()){
              route_callbck({ password : pw }, null);
              console.log(pw + "database.js");
          }else{
              //console.log('wrong password');
              route_callbck(null, null);
          }
        }
      });
};
```

routes.js:

```
var checkLogin = function(req,res){
    var user = req.body.username;
    var pw = req.body.password;
    console.log(user + pw + "routes");

    db.lookup(user, pw, function(data, err) {
          if (data!=null){
              console.log("online"); 
              //req.session.username = user;
              //req.session.password = pw;
          }else{
              res.render('main.ejs',{error:"Fields incorrect"});
          }
    });

};
```

main.ejs:

```
<form method="post" action="/checklogin">
    Enter username here: <br>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder = "Your username"> <br>
    Enter password here: <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder = "Your password">
    <input type="submit" value="Log In">
</form>
```

The functions are all linked up in routes.js when I do module.exports = ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably forget to send the response, make sure

`res.render()` or `res.json()` or `res.send()` gets hit

you should put a try/catch around `JSON.parse()`, that's a best practice.

Looks like your culprit is here:

```
         if (data!=null){
              console.log("online"); 
              //req.session.username = user;
              //req.session.password = pw;

              // you need to send the response here too!  <<<<<
             res.render('main.ejs'); //// !!!
          }else{
              res.render('main.ejs',{error:"Fields incorrect"});
          }
```

Comment: also, get rid of underscored variable names, `route_callbck` should just be `cb`...generally speaking, in Node.js, 99% of the time, no more than one callback is in direct scope. If you use the same variable name for each, `cb` for example, that is a best practice in my opinion.

Comment: Another thing, you should be using error-first callbacks, so this `route_callbck({password: pw}, null);` should be this `cb(null, {password: pw});`

Comment: Thank you so much, Alexander!!! That fixed the problem. For the cb suggestion, are you saying that I should just change that function name to be consistent throughout the entire file?

Comment: Yes, best practice is to use the same variable name, if there are two callbacks in scope, the `cb` in the local scope will shadow the `cb` in the outer scope, etc.

Comment: I'm new to Stack Overflow so it said it took it into consideration but won't let it appear bc I have less than 15 reputation...

Comment: yep, the best way to debug in general is to use logging statements, log your code paths, and if it doesn't get hit within a second or two, something is wrong.